# How to perform a batch insert with SQLAlchemy using "upsert", so an existing key is ignored (or updated) and doesn't crash the exeecution?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have Python code that uses SQLAlchemy for batch insertion with [bulk_insert_mappings](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_insert_mappings). The dataset I need to load may have possible duplicate values, so how best to deal with this situation if there are multiple processes doing parallel imports? It's easy enough for a single batch insert, I can just keep a collection of keys to be added in a set and never add one more than once using this set:

```
            for line in fs.open(json_path[3:]):
                # get dictionary from JSON line
                json_dict = json.loads(line)

                # get the values we'll store in the database columns
                id_hash = json_dict['key']['AddressKeyHash']
                address1 = json_dict['address']['Address1']

                if id_hash not in distinct_hashes:
                    distinct_hashes.add(id_hash)

                    # hold a dictionary mapping columns to values for each row
                    row_mapping = {
                        "id": id_hash,
                        "address1": address1,
                    }
                    mappings.append(row_mapping)
                    count += 1

                # if we've reached the batch size (count is even divisible)
                # then we save the batch
                if (count % batch_size) == 0:
                    self.session.bulk_insert_mappings(Address, mappings)
                    self.session.commit()

                    # clear the mappings list for the next batch
                    mappings = []

            if len(mappings) > 0:
                self.session.bulk_insert_mappings(Address, mappings)
                self.session.commit()
```

If I use the above in parallel there is no way to communicate between the parallel processes as to which keys have already been added. So I wonder if there's a way to add a setting that will allow for how to handle duplicate inserts other than a simple failure/error/crash. For example, how to specify "ignore on duplicate" or "update on duplicate" behavior?

I am using Python with SQLAlchemy. Each job will run on AWS EC2 cluster and executes a single script (much of it above) to perform batch insertion from data in a JSON file on S3 into an Aurora (Postgres) cluster.

Maybe there's a way to utilize multiprocessing for this instead, utilizing multiple cores rather than multiple Batch/EC2 jobs, and somehow utilize a [shared memory object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) to allow the batch insertion processes to communicate? If not then perhaps there's something in place that allows for duplicate inserts to be ignored or treated as an update?

Comment: Perhaps instead of `bulk_insert_mappings` you could use [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#insert-on-conflict-upsert) and call `executemany` yourself ?